# the character moves immediately when the scene starts

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

the character, when starting the scene moves immediately, we need him to move left or right by pressing the buttons, help solve the problem
I add a screenshot of the code that is on the character and a screenshot of the code that is on the buttons

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Why do you set rb twice to the same thing and then have a second variable also pointing to the same thing.. if you do this sort of thing is it too surprising you get weird results?

Answer (score 0):

In Update -which works every frame- your code checks if position is equal to smth and if not adds velocity to gameobject.

If you want this to occur when pressing buttons it's better to use Input.getkeydown event.

fore example:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        run = 1f;
    }else
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        run = -1f;
    }
    else
    {
        run = 0f;
    }
     rb.velocity = new Vector2(run, transform.position.y);
}
```